# IHostedService Asp.Net Core WebAPI cannot access shared drive files and folders after hosting to IIS Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an issue and used many methods to solve it.
I have a HostedService within the ASP.Net Core Web API and it is hosted in IIS Server.
This service will run in background in and executes the function which is search files in shared drive in every defined time interval.
[Image of shared drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAUZe.png)

When I run application from Visual Studio it can find the directories located in shared drive
Eg; **Z:\DIR1\DIR2\DIR3:**
But after I host it in IIS server it cannot find the directory.
I have provided all the permission as windows user has for IIS_IUSRS (*Read & execute, List folder contents, Read, Write*)

Can anybody provide the solution for this problem?

Comment: It is not mandatory to mount the shared folder as a drive. You can access it directly \\server\share\dir1\dir2\dir3. If you want to understand what is going on with file access I recommend you use SysInternals's Process Monitor.

Comment: Hi, I tried using full server path you have mentioned <server ip>\<shared>\dir1\dir2 and still its not able to find the path. Besides, I have also implemented UserImpersonation (SimpleUserImpersonation) My application is in Asp.net core v2.2